# bash: Copy last version of a file from a mask list

Tags: bash, list, loops, for-loop, mask

There is a set of programs in a source folder, but only the most recent version must be copied to the destination USB drive.

From [Bash Script - Copy latest version of a file in a directory recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174207/bash-script-copy-latest-version-of-a-file-in-a-directory-recursively), it shows that my formula would be:

```
f=$(find . -name AdbeRdr\*.exe | sort -n | tail -1)
```

So how to make find work inside a for loop on a set of masks?

```
set1="AdbeRdr\*.exe jre-\*.exe LibreOffice\*.msi"
for m in $set1
do
    echo "m: $m"
    f=$(find . -name $m | sort -n | tail -1)
    echo "f: $f"
    cp $f /media/USB
done
```

`$m` outputs the correct values (AdbeRdr*.exe, etc.), `$f` is empty and `cp` copies the whole parent directory. If I specify the mask explicitly without a variable (`find . -name AdbeRdr\*.exe | sort -n | tail -1`), the last file is outputted correctly.

Where am I going wrong? And how can I handle spaces if those would occur in filenames?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array rather than a string to hold your elements, like this:

```
set1=( 'AdbeRdr*.exe' 'jre-*.exe' 'LibreOffice*.msi' )
for m in "${set1[@]}"
do
    echo "m: $m"
    f=$(find . -name "$m" | sort -n | tail -1)
    echo "f: $f"
    cp "$f" /media/USB
done
```

Use double-quotes around your variables to handle spaces in filenames.